# running single rails unit/functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, automated-tests

As title.

ruby test/functionals/whatevertest.rb doesn't work, that requires me to replace all `require 'test_helper'` to `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'`. For some reason most of those test templates have such issue, so I rather to see if there is a hack I could get around it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a single test from a rails test suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506780/how-to-run-a-single-test-from-a-rails-test-suite)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux?  why not try `(cd test && ruby functionals/whatevertest.rb)`.  Note, the parentheses are important as otherwise your current directory will change to the subdirectory.  What it does is `fork` another shell, change to the subdirectory in it, and run the test.

Comment: thats a good one. I changed a bit to (cd test && ruby functional/whatsoevertest.rb) so it works properly with the relative directory structure. Makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 49):

The following answer is based on: [How to run single test from rails test suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1506780/664833) (stackoverflow)

But very briefly, here's the answer:

```
ruby -I test test/functional/whatevertest.rb
```

For a *specific* `functional` test, run:

```
ruby -I test test/functional/whatevertest.rb -n test_should_get_index
```

Just put underscores in places of spaces in test names (as above), or quote the title as follows:

```
ruby -I test test/functional/whatevertest.rb -n 'test should get index'
```

Note that for `unit` tests just replace `functional` with `unit` in the examples above. And if you're using **bundler** to manage your application's gem dependencies, you'll have to execute the tests with `bundle exec` as follows:

```
bundle exec ruby -I test test/unit/specific_model_test.rb
bundle exec ruby -I test test/unit/specific_model_test.rb -n test_divide_by_zero
bundle exec ruby -I test test/unit/specific_model_test.rb -n 'test divide by zero'
```

**Most importantly**, note that the argument to the `-n` switch is *the name of the test, and the word "test" prepended to it*, with spaces or underscores depending on whether you're quoting the name or not. The reason is that `test` is a convenience method. The following two methods are *equivalent*:

```
test "should get high" do
  assert true
end

def test_should_get_high
  assert true
end
```

...and can be executed as *either* of the following (they are *equivalent*):

```
bundle exec ruby -I test test/integration/misc_test.rb -n 'test should get high'
bundle exec ruby -I test test/integration/misc_test.rb -n test_should_get_high
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpfull. Standard directory is : test/functional/ instead of test/functionals/ so i edited your answer. Thanks

Comment: Oops.. thanks for the edit! I must have mistakenly slipped the _s_ in there because sometimes I execute just the functional tests via `bundle exec rake test:functionals`, which is plural. Note: same for running all unit tests.. just replace `functionals` with `units`.

Comment: @BSeven What version of Ruby are you using with Rails 3.0.7?

Comment: @BSeven what specifically have you tried that doesn't work (you said "this")? I'll assume that have you tried everything above, in which case, you should try `-n test_the_name_of_your_test`, where `test_the_name_of_your_test` is "the name of your test" with `test_` preceding it (and underscores in place of spaces). For example, `-n test_should_create_item`.

Comment: @user664833 - "This" is `ruby -I test test/functional/whatevertest.rb -n selected_test` and `ruby -I test test/functional/whatevertest.rb -n 'selected test w long name'`. Prepending `test_` did not help. In all 3 cases, the output is `
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors`.

Comment: I just installed `rails 3.0.7`, and built a new "depot" app (`rails new depot`), `cd depot`, `bundle install` (to install sqlite3), `rails g scaffold User name:string`, `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate`, and then I ran the following tests with `ruby 1.9.2p290`, and all of them worked: `ruby -I test test/unit/user_test.rb` and `ruby -I test test/unit/user_test.rb -n test_the_truth` and `ruby -I test test/unit/user_test.rb -n 'test_the_truth'`. The test's actual name is "the truth". Also, I am in *the app's root directory*.

Comment: @user664833 - OK, I went through that process and all 3 commands worked. I guess there is something with my gems or monkey patching in my other project that is breaking this functionality. It worked for   a functional test as well. The important thing to know is that the test name must be preceded by `test`:  `test_the_truth`.

Comment: @BSeven I have updated the answer to reflect this. Sorry that it was misleading.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

ruby -Ilib:test test/functionals/whatevertest.rb

Comment: I actually run it with:
ruby -I test test/functional/whatevertest.rb
but it ends up being the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Rails 4, then rake supports file / directory arguments. Example:

```
rake test test/unit/user_test.rb
rake test test/unit
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer for the title question would be:

```
ruby unit/post_test.rb -n selected_test # use to run only one selected test
```

but for the body of the question [tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12950/tvanfosson) gave a good answer.

Comment: I got the following error: `<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)` Does it work with functional test?

Answer (score 4):

After spending endless hours on this, I finally found the solution (in Rails 3.0.7) :

```
ruby -I test test/functional/users_controller_test.rb -n "/the_test_name/"
```

**Note, this only works with underbars (_) in the command. It does not work with spaces!**

Define the test with spaces as:

```
test "the test name" do
```

This solution uses pattern matching, so you can use part of the test name. If the test is "should do foo", then either of the following will work as well.

```
ruby -I test test/functional/alerts_controller_test.rb -n "/foo/"
ruby -I test test/functional/alerts_controller_test.rb -n "/do_foo/"
```

The following (with spaces) ***will not work***:

```
ruby -I test test/functional/alerts_controller_test.rb -n "/do foo/"
```

Comment: I found out that if you escape "space" in pattern It will work. So something like this **works**:
ruby -I test test/my_test.rb -n "/do\ foo/"

Comment: for some reason leaving the spaces worked for me, I'm `ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484` and `>> Rails::version => "2.3.18"`

Answer (score 0):

most conventional method for 2 and 3 is:

ruby -I test test/functional/your_test_file.rb