# How to run a single test from a Rails test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake

How can I run a single test from a Rails test suite?

`rake test ANYTHING` seems to not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [running single rails unit/functional test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274349/running-single-rails-unit-functional-test)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

**NOTE:** *This doesn't run the test via `rake`. So any code you have in `Rakefile` will NOT get executed.*

To run a single test, use the following command from your rails project's main directory:

```sh
ruby -I test test/unit/my_model_test.rb -n test_name
```

This runs a single test named "name", defined in the MyModelTest class in the specified file.  The test_name is formed by taking the test name, prepending it with the word "test", then separating the words with underscores.  For example:

```ruby
class MyModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'valid with good attributes' do
    # do whatever you do
  end

  test 'invalid with bad attributes' do
    # do whatever you do
  end
end
```

You can run both tests via:

```sh
ruby -I test test/unit/my_model_test.rb
```

and just the second test via

```sh
ruby -I test test/unit/my_model_test.rb -n test_invalid_with_bad_attributes
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (on functional or unit tests). I get `0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors`. Rails 3.0.7.

Comment: I'm personally a fan of the regex form: `-n "/good/"`.  Shell escaping is always fun, so I tend to stick to simple regexes, but it's far easier than writing out the full test name all the time.

Comment: It's important to note that for this to work, you should not be in the MAIN directory as specified in the response but in the subdirectory which contain the `test/` folder. For example, if I want to run the test `activesupport/test/core_ext/array_ext_test.rb` I should be in `activesupport/` first.

Comment: @Groxx - Finally a solution! Thank you! `-n "/good/"` worked.

Comment: Be careful running this in 2018+. It bypasses some testing tasks built into rails (like db:test:prepare) which are used for many things, like swapping local data for fixture data, and restoring it again. Running this blew away my local database. Consider a solution that uses the built-in rails testing tasks, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006811/1154642 (which worked for me).

Answer (score 138):

Run a **test file**:

```
rake test TEST=tests/functional/accounts_test.rb
```

Run a **single test** in a test file:

```
rake test TEST=tests/functional/accounts_test.rb TESTOPTS="-n /paid accounts/"
```

*(From @Puhlze 's comment.)*

Comment: Also, if you want to run a single test in in the given file you can add a TESTOPTS environment var which will be passed to the test. E.G. rake test TEST=tests/functional/accounts_test.rb TESTOPTS="-n /paid accounts/"

Comment: if the latter test command doesnt work, try `rake test TEST=tests/functional/accounts_test.rb TESTOPTS="-n '/paid accounts/'"` (enclosing `/paid accounts/` with single quotes)

Comment: Documentation: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rake/13.0.1/Rake/TestTask
https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/doc/command_line_usage.rdoc

Answer (score 53):

Thanks to @James, the answer seems to be:

```
rails test test/models/my_model.rb:22
```

Assuming 22 is the line number of the given test. According to rails help:

> ```
>  $ rails test --help
> ```
>
> You can run a single test by appending a line number to a filename:
>
> ```
>     bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:27
> ```

Also, please note that your test should inherit from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest for this to work (That was my mistake):

```
class NexApiTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
.
.
.
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer based on the Rails guides, at least for testing a specific line.

Answer (score 52):

For rails 5:

```
rails test test/models/my_model.rb
```

Comment: But this runs all test cases in the file, the question asks to run a single test...

Comment: You can run a single test by appending a line number to a filename:`bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:27`

Answer (score 22):

### Rails 5

I used this way to run single test file (all the tests in one file)

```
rails test -n /TopicsControllerTest/ -v
```

Another option is to use the line number (which is printed below a failing test):

```
rails test test/model/my_model.rb:15
```

Comment: this is the best answer to the question for recent rails versions, +1

Comment: Note the word inside a pair of forward slashes can match any of the method names. Just be careful any space has to be replaced with `_`. For example, `-n "/many_num/"` would match `test "many numbers" do` and `test "many numbered items" do` etc.

Comment: in Rails 6, you have to use `rake test TEST=test/models/MyClassTest.rb`

Answer (score 11):

In my situation for `rake` only works `TESTOPTS="-n='/your_test_name/'"`:

```
bundle exec rake test TEST=test/system/example_test.rb TESTOPTS="-n='/your_test_name/'"
```

Comment: I noticed this, too.  I could have sworn it worked without the `=` (the one in `-n=`) in the past, but now it keeps thinking it's a filename instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, now I can finally run specific tests...

Answer (score 5):

To run a single test in the actual Rails suite:

```
bundle exec ruby -I"railties/test" actionpack/test/template/form_options_helper_test.rb
```

Answer (score 4):

That was a silly midnight question of mine. Rails kindly prints the command it is executing upon `rake test`. The rest is a cut and paste exercise.

```
~/projects/rails/actionpack (my2.3.4)$ ruby -I"lib:test" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/controller/base_test.rb"
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to look directly into the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#running-tests

```
cd actionmailer
bundle exec ruby -w -Itest test/mail_layout_test.rb -n test_explicit_class_layout
```

Answer (score 3):

**To re-run a test that just failed**, copy-n-paste the failed *test name* into

```
rails test -n [test-name]
```

#### EXAMPLE

When your test suite reports this:

```
> rails test
   ...
   Error:
   PlayersControllerTest#test_should_show_player:
   ActionView::Template::Error: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

you rerun the failing test with this:

```
rails test -n PlayersControllerTest#test_should_show_player
```

Answer (score 3):

If rake is running MiniTest, the option is `--name` instead of `-n`.

```
rake test TEST=test/unit/progress_test.rb TESTOPTS="--name=testCreate"
```

Comment: Nice one. This was giving me a bit of a headache.

Comment: Funny, I hit that with `Test::Unit`. See https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/490
So you say that it is not about `TestTask` but about the underlying test framework? I believe it is an issue with the `TestTask` though because if I run directly with Ruby, then it works: `bundle exec ruby test/gnuplot_printer_test.rb -n /write/`. idk if that's the same with minitest though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a single test, you can just run them as a regular Ruby script

```
ruby actionmailer/test/mail_layout_test.rb
```

You can also run a whole suite (eg. ActiveRecord or ActionMailer) by `cd`-ing into the directory and running `rake test` inside there.

Comment: Not in Rails -- at least not with the default test files generated. They have "require 'test_helper'" on the first line, but the load path won't have been set up in time. If you change every first line to an explicit require ("require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'test_helper')"), then your solution works.

Comment: ahem, that's `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'test_helper')`

Comment: @Gaius Double-checked. First one doesn't work, but `cd`-ing in does. Just to be clear (I'm not sure if I'm mis-reading this, but you did say "generated test files"), this is for the Rails library itself, *not* a Rails project.

Answer (score 0):

First, access the folder of the lib you want to test(this is important) and then run:

```
~/Projects/rails/actionview (master)$ ruby -I test test/template/number_helper_test.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails folder

```rb
  bundle install
  bundle exec ruby -I"activerecord/test" activerecord/test/cases/relation/where_test.rb
```

Note you need to load appropriate folder: "activerecord/test" (where you have test)