# How to run a single test in Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 using Unit::Test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

Yes I know the same question has been asked ([How to run a single test from a rails test suite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506780/how-to-run-single-test-from-rails-test-suite)), but the solution doesn't seem to work for Rails 3. Maybe it works for Rails 2?

How to run a single test in Rails 3.0.7 using Unit::Test? Not a single test file, but a ***single test***.

```
test "the truth" do
  assert false
end
```

`ruby -I test test/functional/test_file.rb -n "the truth"` generates `0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors`

Answer (score 6):

Try Regular Expressions

```
bundle exec ruby -I test test/functional/test_file.rb -n "/truth/"
```

Answer (score 3):

The "ruby -I (...) -n" method only works for me in Rails 3 like this:

```
bundle exec ruby -I test test/functional/test_file.rb -n "the truth"
```

But then again, I'm using jRuby so YMMV

Comment: What is `test`? I get `0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
`.

Comment: I presume you are referring to 'test' in "-I test"? -I test adds RAILS_ROOT/test directory to the ruby load path.

Comment: try  bundle exec ruby -I test test/functional/test_file.rb -n the_truth

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant `-I test`. I gather it is the text `test`.

Comment: I did `bundle exec ruby -I test test/functional/test_file.rb -n the_truth`, and got `0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
`.

Comment: That's very helpful. I can see that the test is called "test_the_truth". I tried that as well as another test in another file. Putting a `puts` statement inside the test shows that it is not being run...apparently it isn't being found...I wonder what could cause that...

Comment: @BSeven I am also getting same result "Finished in 0.010000s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips"  can you tell me what to do to get successful result.

Answer (score 2):

Try [single_test](https://github.com/grosser/single_test)

Comment: I can't get it to work. The documentation is cryptic and I get `can't modify frozen string`.

Comment: A nice tutorial covering how to use single_test (besides other options) is [here](http://flavio.castelli.name/rails_execute_single_test). It also covers how to run a single test

Comment: Yes, I read that. It doesn't work. The two methods he suggests are `ruby -I` and single_test gem.

Answer (score 2):

For some odd reason, you are supposed to put underscores instead of spaces in your testline and then use regular expression. So this works for me:

```
bundle exec ruby -I test test/functional/test_file.rb -n "/the_truth/"
```

Comment: In Rails 4, this was the only one of the suggested solutions that worked for me.