# How can i test an individual controller in rails 5

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5

suppose you want to test a test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb

`rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb`

the results will be

(static-pages) $ rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb 
Running via Spring preloader in process 2430
Run options: --seed 45024

Running:

..

Finished in 0.900028s, 2.2222 runs/s, 2.2222 assertions/s.

2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run single test from rails test suite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506780/how-to-run-single-test-from-rails-test-suite)

Answer (score 2):

rails test method you have used run all unit, functional and integration tests. To run only a single test you can use invitation test as follows

```
 ruby -Itest test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
```

You can also run a particular test method from the static_pages_controller_test by using the -n switch with the test method name as follows.

```
 ruby -Itest test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb -n test_method_name
```

Hope [this link](https://flavio.castelli.me/2010/05/28/how-to-run-a-single-rails-unit-test/) will help you to get a better idea

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Adam thank you for your feedback. Hope my edit will work